# C# Possible.NullReferenceExcpetion

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

i'm learning C# at the moment and i'm learning all those new concepts and stuff.
I was working on a program for school on which it consists of creating an aquarium that has fish on it and these fish has positions.

The class is initialized:

```
int z = 0,x,y,max;
Peixe[] peixes;
Posicao[] posicoes;
Random rng = new Random();

public Aquario(string nome, int x, int y, int max)
{
    this.nome = nome;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    peixes = new Peixe[max];
    posicoes = new Posicao[max];
}
```

So, in my aquarium there must be a method to shuffle the fish's positions and I did that as follows:

```
public bool AbanarAquario()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        int x = rng.Next(0, this.x);
        int y = rng.Next(0, this.y);

        if (!peixes[i].emagrecer())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            posicoes[i].ChangeX(x);
            posicoes[i].ChangeY(y);
        }

    }
    if (z > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < z; j++)
            {
                if (posicoes[i].comparePos(posicoes[j]))
                {
                    if (peixes[i].mostraPeso() > peixes[j].mostraPeso())
                    {
                        if (!peixes[j].eliminarPeixe())
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            posicoes[j] = null;
                            z--;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!peixes[i].eliminarPeixe())
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            posicoes[i] = null;
                            z--;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So, that uses a method that my position class has and again, is as follows:

```
public bool comparePos(Posicao outro)
{
    if (this.x == outro.x && this.y == outro.y)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, visual studio warns me that there will probably be a null reference exception in the line `if (posicoes[i].comparePos(posicoes[j]))` and I can't figure out why!
Not only this the program actually does crash when I try to shuffle the positions, tried to debug it but i'm not very experienced in the matter so no luck there.

**EDIT**

Initializing position:

```
public bool adicionarPeixe(string nome, string cor, float peso)
    {
        if (z >= peixes.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            int x = rng.Next(0, this.x);
            int y = rng.Next(0, this.y);
            peixes[z] = new Peixe(z, nome, cor, peso);
            peixes[z].Aquario(0);
            posicoes[z] = new Posicao(x,y);
            z++;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see where you are intializating or populating `posicoes` at all. VS is letting you know that if you don't put something in the array, the program will crash. Also, you're setting various elements to null in your loops, so maybe VS is picking up on that.

Comment: my initializing is on the constructor

        Peixe[] peixes;
        Posicao[] posicoes;
        Random rng = new Random();

        public Aquario(string nome, int x, int y, int max)
        {
            this.nome = nome;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            peixes = new Peixe[max];
            posicoes = new Posicao[max];
        }

my max is an input from the user

Comment: comparePos doesn't check if outro could be null.

Comment: But I don't need to check if it's null because the program is done in a way that I will never use a null object

Comment: You've initialized the size of the array, but it's not clear if there are legitimate objects inside that array.  For the most part, arrays can be replaced with the List<T>.

Comment: You've created and initialized the array in the constructor, but it only has null references.  Somewhere you need to instantiate the individual instances of `Posicao`.  In other words, somewhere you need `posicoes[i] = new Posicao();` or something similar to that.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I did that, check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm completely missing it, I don't see where you're defining posicoes. But it sounds like you aren't initializing it.

If you're doing something like,

```
Posicao posicoes;
```

then using it, then the compiler is assuming it's going to be null and warning you.

You need to do something like,

```
Posicao posicoes = new Posicao();
```

So the object exists for you to manipulate. But again, I'm not sure where you're defining it, so this could be off base. Can you update your question with where and how you're defining posicoes.

Also if you are defining it, you can put a simple check in right before you use it, or if you just want to back out of the method if for some reason it is null at the top of the method you can just do,

```
if(posicoes == null)
{
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

Per information about the constructor, your loop is going outside the size of the list. I don't see where Z is being defined, but are you by chance not accounting for 0 based indexing and going over the length of the array by 1?

Put a break point on where you're setting Z and see if it's bigger than the amount of items in your list.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a fair warning. 
The z variable looks like it could be anything. Consider:

Dividing this up into different methods.
Using a foreach() loop instead of a for() loop. (Failing that you use int z = posicoes.Count())

I think the compiler is worried about z=999 when the collection only goes up to 99 or something like that.

Comment: But it's not anything, it's my program counter that says in what position i'm currently am. That should not be an issue